# Use strings as unit test names in PHP

Tags: php, testing

There are some frameworks for languages other than PHP that allows one to use strings to describe tests. Eg: [mocha](https://mochajs.org/)

Something like this:

```
it('should return -1 when the value is not present', function() {
  assert.equal([1,2,3].indexOf(4), -1);
});
```

I wonder if there is anything similar for PHP?
If so, which lib? Can someone do it with PHPUnit?

Best

Comment: Could you give some examples of such frameworks?

Comment: Is there any reason why `public function itShouldValidateTheFirstRequirement()` isn't good enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There appears to be kahlan/kahlan for PHP

```
it("expects methods to be called", function() {
    $user = new User();
    expect($user)->toReceive('save')->with(['validates' => false]);
    $user->save(['validates' => false]);
});
```

> Kahlan is a full-featured Unit & BDD test framework a la RSpec/JSpec
>   which uses a describe-it syntax and moves testing in PHP one step
>   forward.
>
> Kahlan lets you stub or monkey patch your code directly like in Ruby
>   or JavaScript without any required PECL-extensions.

https://github.com/kahlan/kahan